# What's the best way to control S3?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, asp.net-core-webapi

**I am using:**

React as front end,
.net core as back end.
I have s3 bucket

**Purpose: upload file to S3**

allow the users to upload directly via browser ( can be via was sdk or HTTP post)

**What I want to achieve:**

because of the s3 key, I don't want to give the key to one user, otherwise, one user can upload and read other users file.

I don't want to pass the file to the server, then upload via server.

What's the best way for me to control this? getting a unique key via the my backend server for a particular user?

Or any suggested link/training I can go to?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an S3 presigned POST URL in the backend using the secret access keys of an appropriate IAM user (let's call it User A). Then return this presigned POST URL to the client, and now client can use this presigned POST URL upload files to S3 bucket on behalf of User A. Here is the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html) which describes how to POST an object to S3 in detail.